# getting warning when use in_array and multidimensional-array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, yii

I make a array and fill it by variables(index and value) by code in php(yii framework). but my program don't work good.I cannot use my array after fill.

in model Lookup.php

```
private static $row_flags= array();
private static $table_flags= array();


public static function checkStatus($value,$row,$column) {

    $thresholds= hreshold::model()->findAll(array('select'=>$row.','.$column));
    self::$row_flags['browsing'][$row][$column]=($value < $thresholds[0]->$row) ?"green":(($value > $thresholds[0]->$column)?"red":"yellow");
    return self::$row_flags['browsing'][$row][$column];

}

public static function getRowFlag() {

        return self::$row_flags;

    }

public static function row_color($table,$row){

   return in_array("yellow",self::$row_flags['browsing'][$row]);
  }
```

view.php

```
<?php 
    lookup::checkStatus(3001,'http','access');
    lookup::checkStatus(3001,'http','access');
    lookup::checkStatus(3001,'http','core');
    lookup::checkStatus(3001,'http','blackbox');
    lookup::checkStatus(3001,'http','gateway');
    lookup::checkStatus(3001,'http','internet');

    print_r(lookup::getRowFlag());
?>
     Array
      (
           [browsing] => Array
                           (
                              [http] => Array
                                          (
                                              [access] => yellow
                                              [core] => yellow
                                              [blackbox] => yellow
                                              [gateway] => yellow
                                              [internet] => yellow
                                           )
                            )
      )
```

if I call `Lookup::row_color('browsing','http')` in view I have

> warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: Your code looks good. Show the full view and model.

Comment: I tried your code, seems fine to me.  I tried `var_dump(lookup::getRowFlag());var_dump(Lookup::row_color('browsing','http'));` And first return an array, the other one true... What is the problem? Do you use `checkStatus()` before?

Comment: Actually u need to check array_key_exist for browsing index and also for $row  and then is_array .... because when this code executed not everytime  self::$row_flags['browsing'][$row] will be array so better check that and return FALSE or something.... as mentioned in answer.

Comment: @JaiminMosLake i print_r from my array there are all key and value.

Comment: @maryam may be you print_r and exit so when there is another key instead of "http" ... there is chance there will not be an array so... it is good to make check for this things.... just try once to make a check in if else way and print something in each else loop for the key so you will get better idea of this... Ur coding is right just make it more perfect and error handling....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe column is the troublemaker:
Instead of `l(array('select'=>$row.','.$column));`

Use `l(array('select'=>$row.','.'select'=>$column));`

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
public static function row_color($table,$row){
  if (is_array(self::$row_flags['browsing'][$row])) {
    return in_array("yellow",self::$row_flags['browsing'][$row]);
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The question was about accessing fiiled array. She doesn't need array cheeck.

Comment: @SiZE This was an attempt if the error was something what Jaimin Moslake has mentioned in the comments.

Comment: As OP is just concerned about warnings, there is no data loss mentioned. Thx!